# How to cleanup double profiles in sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I recently restored my quality profiles from a different sonar server twice, as the first one didn't seem to work in one go and I thought that the second would overwrite the first one. However, they did not and I was left with 2 exactly the same profiles in sonar with the same ID. I had to go in to the sonar database and remove them manually, as sonar wouldn't start anymore. Now I am left with rules which are in 3 different profiles, 2 of which do not exist anymore. How do I clean this up, without disturbing the still valid profile?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to remove parameters from active rules linked on profiles that do not exists anymore :

```
DELETE FROM active_rule_parameters
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT active_rule_parameters.id
  FROM active_rule_parameters
  WHERE active_rule_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT active_rules.id
    FROM active_rules
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT *
        FROM rules_profiles
        WHERE active_rules.profile_id = rules_profiles.id
    )));
```

Then you need to remove active rules linked on profiles that do not exists anymore :

```
DELETE FROM active_rules
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT active_rules.id
  FROM active_rules
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT *
      FROM rules_profiles
      WHERE active_rules.profile_id = rules_profiles.id
  ));
```

Comment: I am first checking if what the results would be when I do a select * instead of a delete, and there were no results. So nothing would be deleted

Comment: It's strange, as I've tried them before. Here's the use case I've used : 1-> Create a new profile, 2-> Activate some rules on it, 3-> Delete the profile in db. Then executing the 2 SQL queries has removed orphan active rules and active rule parameters.

Comment: One question : have you executed both queries or only the first one ?

Comment: I have run both on select instead of delete. Change your use case to add 2 profiles with the same name and then remove 1 in the DB, with both having the same rules to it